# When I send a request array via POST on RestTemplate I receive error 400

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, resttemplate

There is an external service called

http://externalServer:9000/pathServer/serviceCalled

This service as an input parameter receives a list of objects.

```
Request
    [
        { "atr1" : "value" },
        { "atr1" : "value" },
        { "atr1" : "value" },
        { "atr1" : "value" }
    ]
```

In my back end I make the call to this service since it is not in my domain. For this I use Spring's RestTemplate.

I've already used this, but when I make the call, it gives me a 400 bad request error.

This is my code.

```
String jsonValue= "[{ \"atr1\" : \"value\" },{ \"atr1\" : \"value\" },{ \"atr1\" : \"value\" },{ \"atr1\" : \"value\" }]";

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(jsonValue,headers);

String url = "http://externalServer:9000/pathServer/serviceCalled";

ResponseEntity<String> STRresponse = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

The output print to STResponse is

[image]

I know the request is correct because when I send it with postman it works fine.

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: i try but i recive an error

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@7bb08eeb; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token

Comment: You did post an object according to the message, not a list

Comment: But the service receives a list, that I can not change it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using RequestEntity instead of HTTPEntity?

Spring's javadoc has an example you can follow along.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/RequestEntity.html

Comment: i tried but the result is the same ERROR 400 bad request

Answer (score 0):

As already said in comments, try using some class `Request` with a field named `atr1`, and some other class `Result` with two fields named `code` and `message`:

```
class Request {
    private String atr1;
    // getter, setter
}

class Result {
    private String code;
    private String message;
    // getter, setter
}
```

then

```
List<Request> data = new ArrayList<>();
Request req1 = new Request();
req1.setAtr1("value");
data.add(req1);
Request req2 = new Request();
req2.setAtr1("value");
data.add(req2);

String url = "http://externalServer:9000/pathServer/serviceCalled";
ResponseEntity<Result> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, data, Result.class);
```

Comment: I recievied this error Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@11c07e0d; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@11c07e0d; line: 1, column: 1]

Comment: @EliasVargas My bad the result is an object not a string (I did copy your code), see my edit

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with rest template in delete method and after long hour debugging found it! this issue related to use incorrect configure of `ClientHttpRequestFactory` class that use in rest template, use another one like `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` and so on for example me use below code to all method support carries of body message:

```
public class CustomSimpleClientHttpRequestFactory extends 
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory {

    @Override
    protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, String httpMethod) 
    throws IOException {
        super.prepareConnection(connection, httpMethod);

        connection.setDoOutput(true);
    }
}
```

And configure it in RestTemplate like below:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new CustomSimpleClientHttpRequestFactory());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
/* and other configure you like*/
```